# Problema ao receber valores inteiros randômicos em array

Tags: java, array, random

O Eclipse não aponta nenhum erro no código, porém não executa.

```
package gerarOrganizar;
import java.util.Random;
public class GerarOrganizar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i=0;
        int[]ranF =null;
        ranF=new int[100];
        int ran=0;

        for(i=0;i<=100;i++){
            ran=new Random().nextInt(250);
            ranF[i]=ran;
            System.out.print(ran);//mandei imprimir apenas para saber se os valores 
                                  //estão sendo gerados, mas também não imprimiu.
        }//for
    }//main    
}//class
```

Comment: Você está tentando acessar o elemento 101 do array que possui apenas 100. Quando define `new int[100]` pode acessar **no máximo o ranF[99]** ou estará fora dos limites. PS `for(i=0;i<100;i++)` e sugiro também trocar por `System.out.println`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O Eclipse não aponta nenhum erro pois você não está enfrentando um problema de sintaxe, e sim de lógica. O seu código até roda, mas é interrompido durante sua execução devido ao lançamento de uma exceção.

O seu `for` está usando o `i` como contador, e está indo de 0 até 100, no total, ele executará o *loop* por 101 vezes. Entretanto seu array `ranF` só suporta 100 posições, quando o *loop* for executado pela 101ª vez será lançada uma exceção pois você está tentando escrever uma posição além da última. Mude seu `for` para que ele seja executado 100 vezes ao invés de 101, assim:

```
for(i=0;i<100;i++){
```

Repare que o `System.out.print()` manda imprimir tudo na mesma linha do seu console, para ficar mais legível você pode quebrar a linha ou concatenar um espaço entre cada número impresso. Exemplo:

```
System.out.println(ran);
```

ou:

```
System.out.print(ran + " ");
```

Answer (score 5):

Achei o código bem confuso e o reescrevi para tentar entender e funcionou desta forma:

```
package gerarOrganizar;
import java.util.Random;
public class GerarOrganizar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numerosAleatorios = new int[100];
        Random geradorRandomico = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            numerosAleatorios[i] = geradorRandomico.nextInt(250);
            System.out.println(numerosAleatorios[i]); //deixei para você ver funcionando
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/s5fJXx). E [no **Coding Ground**](http://tpcg.io/8fZoSJ). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Math/RandomRange.java).

Answer (score 0):

Nas respostas existentes, senti falta de coesão no código.

Da página de [desambiguação do verbete *Cohesion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion?wprov=sfti1), na Wikipedia em inglês, podemos perceber que coesão se trata de uma "medida de relacionamento entre partes". Lá tem até mesmo uma entrada sobre coesão de código:

> [Cohesion (computer science)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)?wprov=sfti1), a measure of how well the lines of source code within a module work together

Em tradução livre (grifo meu):

> Coesão (ciência da computação), uma *medida* de quão bem as linhas do código fonte internas a um módulo *trabalham junto*

Nos exemplos, não se primou pela coesão do código, mas pela sua coerência. Não havia relacionamento forte entre o tamanho do vetor e a quantidade de elementos da iteração. Se houvesse alguma mudança no tamanho do vetor, para manter a coerência, seria necessário também editar o limite da iteração. Isso é devido à falta de coesão entre o tamanho do vetor e a iteração.

Para dar uma maior coesão ao código, temos algumas possibilidades. Uma delas é por em uma constante o tamanho do vetor, chamando-a sempre que ela for necessária. Mas a minha favorita é perguntar ao próprio vetor qual é o seu tamanho, através de `numerosAleatorios.length`, um atributo que fornece o tamanho do vetor em questão. Mais detalhes [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/208880/64969).

Adaptei o código da [resposta do @Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/35299/64969) para exemplificar a coesão;

```
package gerarOrganizar;
import java.util.Random;
public class GerarOrganizar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numerosAleatorios = new int[100];
        Random geradorRandomico = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < numerosAleatorios.length; i++) {
            numerosAleatorios[i] = geradorRandomico.nextInt(250);
            System.out.println(numerosAleatorios[i]); //deixei para você ver funcionando
        }
    }
}
```

Aumentar a coesão do código é considerado uma *boa prática*, porque quando usada corretamente vai ajudar na manutenção do código em um momento posterior. Você não é obrigado a usá-la e também ela pode ser negativa se você quiser aumentar a coesão de um código apenas para deixá-lo mais coeso, sem facilitar na real sua manutenção.

Você pode muito bem ter um código extremamente não coeso, porém funcional e coerente, mas isso normalmente implica em ser extremamente disciplinado (quanto maior o código, maior a disciplina necessária para mantê-lo coerente).