# Por que em Java o tamanho de um array é um atributo e de uma String é um método?

Tags: java, array, string, característica-linguagem, método

Em Java, o tamanho de um *array* de qualquer objeto pode ser obtido com `length`, que seria um atributo. Mas no caso da `String` é `length()`, um método. Porém, se tiver um *array* de `String`, usa `length`, um atributo. Por que?

Por exemplo:

```
    int[] a = {1,2};
    String b = "str";
    String[] c = {"aa", "bb"};

    a.length;
    b.length();
    c.length;
```

Comment: array !=  String. `length` é uma variavel final e publica de arrays, que retornam o tamanho definido por você ai iniciar o array. Já o método `length()` retorna quantos caracteres tem numa String.

Comment: `length` em um array é um atributo previamente conhecido, enquanto em uma string isso pode ser alterado para por questão de otimização de memória em substrings, não prendendo assim seu valor ao tamanho real do container de informação

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Arrays` são tratados de forma diferente de `Strings`, `ArrayLists` ou qualquer outra coisa que pode ser contado em Java. Um `Array` é praticamente um tipo nativo e seu comprimento não pode ser alterado depois que ele for inicializado, por isso não há necessidade de encapsulamento. A variável de comprimento pode ser diretamente exposto, sem efeitos colaterais.

A razão pela qual `Strings` usa um método em vez de uma variável é porque ela usa internamente um `char[]`que não deseja expor publicamente(por razões de imutabilidade/encapsulamento), por isso envolve a variável de comprimento em um método `length()`. É a mesma razão do `ArrayList` ter um método `size()` em vez de uma variável `length`.

<sup>*Traduzido de [What's the difference between length and length()?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8675694/5524514)*</sup>

Apenas lembrando que uma `String` em si também é imutável, e não somente o array de `char` usado internamente por ela, como pode ser confirmado na [documentação da classe](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: String tb é imutável. Na verdade até mais que o *array*. O real motivo é gambi :) E o C# cometeu o mesmo erro. Bom, até existe um motivo meio semântico, no uso da palavra mesmo. Uma curiosidade é a diferença entre *size*, *length* e *count*

Comment: @bigown imutável serve para garantir que nenhum outro processamento acabe com um conjunto de dados previamente esperado

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado pode ler sobre o assunto em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101.

Comment: @bigown adicionei essa informação na resposta, pra evitar mal entendidos com essa classe.

Comment: @bigown, naveguei um pouco na pergunta que me mandaste e achei isso aqui, também relevante: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/103460/64969

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado pena que tudo o que é respondido mais recentemente dá menos ibope, essa fala de algumas coisas importantes.

Answer (score 15):

Fui pesquisar porque queria saber o motivo. Conclui que só há especulações, ninguém sabe o real motivo. Só os desenvolvedores podem responder isto.

O que me parece claro é que o fato do *array* ser uma construção de linguagem seria mais adequado ter uma propriedade do que um método fantasma que a linguagem trata. Mais ainda, como isto foi uma das primeiras coisas criadas na linguagem talvez não pensaram que um método poderia ser melhor e mais consistente.

`String` é uma classe comum e Java não tem propriedades que apenas encapsulam métodos de acesso, ou seja, só poderia ter o campo exposto se não usasse um método. Criaria problemas de compatibilidade entre implementações, versões e até ficaria inconsistente com outras estruturas que precisam do método, um caso é o [`CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html). Até não é tão necessário assim já que `String` é imutável, o seu valor não é para mudar.

Existem outras teorias, incluindo as listadas aqui, mas elas não me parecem fazer sentido porque mesmo um campo público poderia ser colocado seu valor sempre que necessário. Talvez tenham percebido que assim haveria um atributo novo ocupando espaço que poderia ou não ser necessário.

[Não sou fã do termo atributo que sequer é usado na linguagem. Ela usa campo para isto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 8):

Apenas para dar mais detalhes à [resposta do @user28595](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/208883/64969).

Como o [@Maniero notou em seu comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/208880/porque-em-java-o-tamanho-de-um-array-%c3%a9-um-atributo-e-de-uma-string-e-um-m%c3%a9todo/208883#comment427187_208883), strings são entidades imutáveis. Nos outros comentários foram colocados mais links sobre o assunto da imutabilidade. Um dos aspectos que faz essa imutabilidade importante é uma questão de otimização: operações de `substring` no Java podem ser implementadas de maneira muito leve ([fonte](http://www.programcreek.com/2013/09/the-substring-method-in-jdk-6-and-jdk-7/)). Dependendo da implementação do Java, uma substring pode ser implementada como um conjunto contínuo de informações de um vetor de caracteres. Do exemplo citado na fonte, no JDK6 `"abcde".substring(1,3)` vai gerar um novo objeto *string*, sendo que esse carrega consigo o mesmo vetor de caracteres `{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'}`da *string* inicial, mas ele considera que começa da posição `1` (`b`) e vai até logo antes da posição `3`, portanto seria a posição `2` (`c`). Nem sempre uma implementação Java garante que uma *string* tenha o tamanho do vetor de caracteres que carrega seus dados, possivelmente pode ser que carregue apenas parte dele. Se for o caso da *string* armazenar o índice de início e o de fim, o método `length()` retorna `fim - comeco`; se for implementado com `offset` do primeiro caractere e `count`, então o resultado do método seria `count` (conforme o exemplo que ele deu de como era no JDK6). Se a implementação de *string* fizer uma cópia do *subvetor* desejado é usado (como o exemplo informa que fazem no JDK7), então o método `length()` retorna simplesmente `vetorDeChar.length`.

Uma vantagem de implementar o `string.length()` como método é que se pode alterar completamente a implementação interna (inclusive campos existentes) sem que o programador que usa uma *string* seja afetado. Para aplicações menores, as estratégias de implementação de *string* não são sentidas inicialmente.

> [@Maniero fala sobre o encapsulamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/208921/64969) de propriedades de acesso que poderiam resolver essa idiossincrasia do Java

Um ponto interessante sobre vetores é que o acesso ao seu tamanho é otimizado pela JVM. Existe um *bytecode* especializado em fazer isso: `0xBE`, identificado pelo mnemônico `arraylength`. Usar esse *bytecode* específico tem um resultado gerado menor do que o que seria gerado caso fosse usado o *bytecode* tradicional de se pegar campos, o `getfield` (`0xB4`), que exige mais dois bytes adicionais para o índice do atributo. A [Wikipedia tem uma página listando os bytecodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings).