# Como consigo o tamanho de uma String em Java?

Tags: java, string, orientação-a-objetos

> Estou criando um Banco falso em **java** mas não sei como verificar se a senha tem 8 caracteres.

```
public void criarSenha(){
 String senhacriada = (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Qual a senha ?"));
       if(tamanhodasenhacriada >= 8) {       //! O problema está aqui !
   System.out.println("Senha criada com sucesso !"); 
 }else {
   System.err.println("senha >= 8 !"); 
 }
}
```

> Como eu faço para descobrir o tamanho da String ?

Em **javascript** eu faço :

```
if(lenght(senha) >= 8){
// Codigo
}
```

Mas em Java eu não sei pois estou começando a aprender !

Comment: Uma dica para você que está começando: quando não souber o funcionamento de alguma classe, sugiro procurar a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length()) da mesma.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica @nullptr !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use o método `length()`, pois este irá retornar *o tamanho de uma string em **caracteres***.

Seu código ficará:

```
if(senhacriada.length() >= 8) {       //! A solução está aqui !
   System.out.println("Senha criada com sucesso !"); 
 }else {
   System.err.println("senha >= 8 !"); 
 }
```

Recomendo a leitura:

[Por que em Java o tamanho de um array é um atributo e de uma String e um método?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/208880/por-que-em-java-o-tamanho-de-um-array-%C3%A9-um-atributo-e-de-uma-string-e-um-m%C3%A9todo)

Comment: Vou testar ! Obrigado !

Comment: Muito Obrigado Luiz Augusto !

Comment: 1+Funcionou :D !